# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'translate' while removing punctuation from text

Tags: python, attributeerror

I'm getting this error while trying to remove punctuation from text.

```
train_pos_no_punctuation = remove_punctuation(train_pos)

def remove_punctuation(from_text):
    table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
    stripped = [w.translate(table) for w in from_text]
    return stripped
```

train_pos has type

```
<class 'list'>
```

and the following form:

```
[['hello', 'there', 'world!'], ['i', '"like"', 'potatoes.']]
```

After applying the function I want to get the result:

```
[['hello', 'there', 'world'], ['i', 'like', 'potatoes']]
```

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of lists.

try:

```
train_pos_no_punctuation = [remove_punctuation(i) for i in train_pos]
```